# Updating column with value from other table, can't use distinct function

Tags: sql-server, join, distinct

[image: table]

My original data is in Table2.  I created Table1 from scratch.  I populated Column A like this:

```
INSERT INTO Table1("item")
SELECT DISTINCT(Table2."item")
FROM Table2
```

I populated Table1.Totals (Column B) like this:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET totals = t2.q
    FROM Table1 INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT t2."item"
        , SUM(t2.quantity) AS q
        FROM t2
        GROUP BY t2."item"
    ) AS t2
    ON Table1."item" = t2."item"
```

How can I populate Table1."date"?  My UPDATE above doesn't work here because I can't use an aggregate function on a date.  I was able to get the results I wanted using the following code in a separate query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Table1."item"
, Table2."date"
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2
ON Table1."item" = Table2."item"
ORDER BY Table1."item"
```

But how do I use the results of this query to SET the value of the column?  I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: What date should you choose if there is more than one?, why can't you use an aggregate function on a date column?

Comment: You need to explain which date that you want. There is no ANY() or ARBITRARY() function in T-SQL. What happens if Orange has two different dates?

Comment: Also, please don't put double-quotes around column names. Makes it so hard to read and also relies on `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` settings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can't do the insert all over again, as @Lamak suggested, then you could perform an `UPDATE` this way:

```
UPDATE t1
  SET t1.Date = s.Date
  FROM Table1 AS t1
  INNER JOIN 
  (
    SELECT Item, [Date] = MAX([Date]) -- or MIN()
      FROM Table2
      GROUP BY Item
  ) AS s
  ON t1.Item = s.Item;
```

Comment: Does it seem like you may have accidentally switched t1 and t2?

Comment: Yep, sorry, usually Table1 exists BEFORE Table2. I think it should have been easy enough to interchange those. <shrug>

Comment: This successfully filled in the column with what I had requested, though now I think my original request wasn't fully thought-through.

I will be appending new data to Table2 every day, with the new data having a new date.  I think I need to figure out how exactly I plan to then fill in the date I need in Table1.

Comment: So you plan to run an update or other data-moving operation every day? Have you considered a view instead, so you don't have to do this heavy lifting and so that the data is always accurate, instead of only immediately after you perform the data move?

Answer (score 4):

For SQL Server you coul've use a single `INSERT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO Table1(Item, Totals, [Date])
SELECT Item, SUM(Quantity), MIN([Date]) -- It could be MAX([Date])
FROM Table2
GROUP BY Item
```

Comment: It seems I overcomplicated things, ha.  This seems to do what I need for Column B.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a simple CTAS (create table as select):

```
select item as item, SUM(quantity) as Q, MIN(date) as d into table2
from table1
group by item
```

Comment: You got the tables backwards (like I did) and the user also said the second table was already created and populated. With `SELECT INTO` you lose things that may have already been created on the destination table (indexes, constraints, triggers, permissions, certain dependencies, etc...).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a table, you could create a *view*, using a select statement like in [@Lamak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9182052/297408). That way you wouldn't have to update the new row set each time the `Table2` updates.

Comment: Table2 will only be updated once a day, and each record will have its corresponding date next to it.  Table1 will be updated after I have appended the new day's records to Table2.  Would a view really be necessary here?  Once Table2 is updated, I will be appending new data to Table1.  Old data will never be touched again.

Comment: @eek142: In that case your original approach (calculating the totals once and storing them in a table) seems more appropriate.